# Draw network graph

Tags: javascript, angularjs, canvas, graph

I need help with drawing graph. In this graph must be one main node and any count of child nodes. Every node has owner weight and depending of weight size of nodes must be change.

I try using vis.js but it is not very flexible. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0zpp.png)

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clearly state your question. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SigmaJs chart library [link](http://sigmajs.org/) it might be what you are looking for  and also take a look at Cytoscape.js [link](http://js.cytoscape.org/)